# org babel :exports always exporting both code and results

Tags: org-export, org-babel

It seems that `:exports` option has no influence when exporting to HTML or PDF. 
I am using Org 9.0.9 and Emacs 25.1.1.

The following code, for example, even with `:exports=none` both code and results are exported to the output.

```
 #+TITLE: my document
 #+AUTHOR: Alice Bob

 * one section
  ia oja jofij aofjodfj
 ** sub section
 sd sssioj oi j

 #+NAME: named-block
 #+HEADER: :var data=2
 #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports none
   (message "data:%S" data)
 #+END_SRC

 #+RESULTS: named-block
 : data:2
```

Anyone has the same issue?

[image: output of export]

Comment: The same problem setting the variable in a file using: # -*- org-export-babel-evaluate: nil -*- org-9.4.5 emacs-27.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this issue is related to the following line in my init.el file:

`(setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)`

I've commented it, and now :exports is working properly.